# Is anyone else having a problem with AWS AMPLIFY ERROR code ERESOLVE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, npm

I keep getting this error anytime I try to install anything:

```
npm install @aws-cdk/aws-s3
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native@0.69.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"16 || 17" from @react-native-picker/picker@2.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-picker/picker
npm ERR!     peer @react-native-picker/picker@">=1.2" from aws-amplify-react-native@6.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/aws-amplify-react-native
npm ERR!       aws-amplify-react-native@"^6.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     @react-native-picker/picker@"^2.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || 0.60 - 0.69 || 1000.0.0" from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@"^1.17.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.59" from @react-native-community/netinfo@9.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/netinfo@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (@react-native-picker/picker, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     peer react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || 0.60 - 0.69 || 1000.0.0" from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage
npm ERR!       @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@"^1.17.7" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-native@">=0.59" from @react-native-community/netinfo@9.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo
npm ERR!       @react-native-community/netinfo@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     11 more (@react-native-picker/picker, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I believe its because a conflict with firebase, but I have already uninstalled everything from there... Has anybody else had this problem installing 'aws-cdk.aws-s3'.